# How to paste control characters in gnome-terminal?

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, gvim, gnome-terminal

System: Ubuntu 18.04
Question: How can I copy a string that includes control characters such as ctrl-a, e.g. from gvim (fenc=ascii or utf-8), and paste it including control characters in gnome-terminal?

Use case:
I use "screen", I saved a file with some commands I want to re-run manually occasionally, e.g. open a new screen tab (ctrl-a, ctrl-c), followed by commands, then split (ctrl-a, S), resize (ctrl-a, :, resize )...
It would be very useful to be able to copy-paste all control characters.
I edit my source file with gvim, copying from gvim to another gvim window via the clipboard works (i.e. copies the control characters). But pasting in gnome-terminal (ctrl-shift-v, or shift-ins, or middle-click) seems to strip all control characters.

What do I need to configure so control characters are not stripped?